# Как вычислить размер занимаемый блоками на js?

Tags: javascript

Есть блок, в котором много элементов. Для адаптивности нужно определить, влезают ли элементы в размер экрана и если да, то не показывать элементы скролинга.

Вот такой код:

```js
var buttonRight = document.querySelector('.viewport .right');
var buttonLeft = document.querySelector('.viewport .left');
buttonRight.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var items = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper .item');
  var countItems = items.length;
  var c = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden').length;
  if ((countItems - c) > 1) {
    for (var i = 0; i < countItems - 1; i++) {
      if (!items[i].classList.contains('hidden')) {
        items[i].classList.add('hidden');
        break;
      }
    }
  }
});
buttonLeft.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var items = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper .item');
  var countItems = items.length;
  var c = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden').length;
  if (c > 0) {
    for (var i = countItems; i > 0; i--) {
      if (items[i - 1].classList.contains('hidden')) {
        items[i - 1].classList.remove('hidden');
        break;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.viewport {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.left,
.right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 50;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  background: unset;
  background-image: linear-gradient( 90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  cursor: pointer;
  fill: #777;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient( -90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
}

.left:hover,
.right:hover {
  fill: #000;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #579;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #777;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.item:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: -1px;
}

.item:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #579;
  z-index: 40;
  color: #000;
}

.item.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="viewport">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a class="item" href="#">Lorem</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">ipsum</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">dolor</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">sit</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">amet</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">consectetur</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">adipiscing</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">elit</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Phasellus</a>
  </div>
  <button class="left">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M16.67 0l2.83 2.829-9.339 9.175 9.339 9.167-2.83 2.829-12.17-11.996z"/></svg>
   </button>
  <button class="right">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M5 3l3.057-3 11.943 12-11.943 12-3.057-3 9-9z"/></svg>
   </button>
</div>
```

Comment: element.getBoundingClientRect() ??

Comment: @StrangerintheQ не большой спец в js, а как это поможет? Сделал на `offsetWidth` https://codepen.io/aliencash/pen/jJVRyo , но может быть есть проще вариант?

Comment: не понятно из листинга что у Вас не получилось, я на мобилке смотрю

Comment: @StrangerintheQ если смотреть на десктопе, то все блоки `item` могут вполне вмещаться в размер экрана и даже место останется. но правая стрелка будет работать все равно, т.е. сдвигать блоки оставляя все больше места справа. Вот я и хочу определить влезают ли блоки в экран и сдвигать их только когда не влезают.

Comment: Не легче готовый слайдер поставить?)

Comment: @DaemonHK, проще, но мы экономим время загрузки.

Answer (score 2):

Добавил функцию, она складывает ширину всех элементов с классом `.item` и без класса `.hidden`:

```
function updateVisibility() {
  let size = document.querySelector('.viewport').clientWidth;
  let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.item:not(.hidden)');
  let sum = [].slice.call(elements).reduce((acc, el) => acc + el.clientWidth, 0)
  document.querySelector('button.right').style.display = size-sum<0 ? 'block': 'none';
}
```

И добавил вызовы этой функции на обработчики ваших кнопок, а так же при загрузке и при изменении размеров окна, правда это можно было бы сделать при помощи [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver), но вопрос не про это

```js
var buttonRight = document.querySelector('.viewport .right');
var buttonLeft = document.querySelector('.viewport .left');
buttonRight.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var items = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper .item');
  var countItems = items.length;
  var c = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden').length;
  if ((countItems - c) > 1) {
    for (var i = 0; i < countItems - 1; i++) {
      if (!items[i].classList.contains('hidden')) {
        items[i].classList.add('hidden');
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  updateVisibility();
});
buttonLeft.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var items = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper .item');
  var countItems = items.length;
  var c = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden').length;
  if (c > 0) {
    for (var i = countItems; i > 0; i--) {
      if (items[i - 1].classList.contains('hidden')) {
        items[i - 1].classList.remove('hidden');
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  
  updateVisibility();
});

window.onresize = updateVisibility;

updateVisibility();

function updateVisibility() {
  let size = document.querySelector('.viewport').clientWidth;
  let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.item:not(.hidden)');
  
  let sum = [].slice.call(elements).reduce((acc, el) => acc + el.clientWidth, 0)
  console.log(size-sum);

  document.querySelector('button.right').style.display = size-sum<0 ? 'block': 'none';
}
```

```css
.viewport {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.left,
.right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 50;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  background: unset;
  background-image: linear-gradient( 90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  cursor: pointer;
  fill: #777;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient( -90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
}

.left:hover,
.right:hover {
  fill: #000;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #579;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #777;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.item:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: -1px;
}

.item:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #579;
  z-index: 40;
  color: #000;
}

.item.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="viewport">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a class="item" href="#">Lorem</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">ipsum</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">dolor</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">sit</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">amet</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">consectetur</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">adipiscing</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">elit</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Phasellus</a>
  </div>
  <button class="left">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M16.67 0l2.83 2.829-9.339 9.175 9.339 9.167-2.83 2.829-12.17-11.996z"/></svg>
   </button>
  <button class="right">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M5 3l3.057-3 11.943 12-11.943 12-3.057-3 9-9z"/></svg>
   </button>
</div>
```

Однако, способ очень спорный, т.к. это все можно сделать намного проще. Но уже не с Вашей версткой

Comment: что поменялось-то?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ `Однако, способ очень спорный, т.к. это все можно сделать намного проще. Но уже не с Вашей версткой` Дак я не против поменять верстку. Скажите только что с ней не так...

Comment: @StrangerintheQ На основе вашей идеи о том, что хорошо бы пересчитывать размеры при ресайзе сделал такой вариант https://codepen.io/aliencash/pen/VRpdNq

Comment: @AndreyFedorov вполне работоспособно

Comment: @AndreyFedorov возможен вариант верстки, при котором можно будет не заниматься вычислением суммы ширин, а просто взять размер родителя

Comment: @StrangerintheQ спасибо, правда "работоспособно" звучит как забивание гвоздя в крышку гроба моих усилий. =)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ мне кажется это меньшая из проблем. меня беспокоит, что я внутри каждой функции вычисляю одни и теже указатели на элементы в DOM. Но как по другому я пока не знаю...

Comment: @AndreyFedorov ну зачем же так, нужно добиться чтобы того, чтобы див снаружи имел размер содержимого и брать его размер